# How to randomly distribute a continuosly growing database?

Tags: probability

There is a set $T_k$ with a finite amount of elements. At a given time, I know only a subset $S_k$, where $n = |S_k|$, and $n < |T_k|$. Now, a new element $e \notin T_k$ is inserted into $T_k$ to form $T_{k+1} = T_k \cup \{e\}$. I now have to decide how to build  $S_{k+1}$ considering new element $e$. I may either:

1. Throw away $e$, and make $S_{k+1} = S_k$;
2. Decide to replace a random element $r \in S_k$ with $e$ in order to form $S_{k+1} = (S_k -\{r\}) \cup \{e\}$, so that $|S_{k+1}| = n$.

If I have the same probability of finding any element of $T_k$ in $S_k$, how can I decide how to build $S_{k+1}$, in order to maintain the same probability of finding any element of $T_{k+1}$ in $S_{k+1}$?

Background information: I am trying to devise a mechanism for distributing Bitcoin's blockchain among the running clients, instead of everyone having to hold a full copy of the database. A node must have the same probability of finding any given block stored locally, and at every new block a client must decide if it is going to be stored (replacing an old block) or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want the probability of having stored *any* given element in $T_{k+1}$ to be $n/|T_{k+1}|$. That includes $e$! So with probability $n/|T_{k+1}|$, accept $e$; otherwise, throw it away.

Comment: Is it correct that I choose $r$ randomly, so that probability of finding any other elements is $n/|T_{k+1}|$, too?

Comment: Yes, that's right!